# Stargate Home Symbol

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis, stargate-universe, stargate-movie

I'm struggling to find and I'm pretty sure I didn't imagine this:
From one of the Stargate's (Movie, SG1, SGA or SGU) - I remember the home symbol being two Anubis? guards leaning into the sun.

However I cant find an image anywhere.

In which movie/series did this show?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's from the original movie. Daniel was the one who realized that the two squiggles were stick figures and drew them with a sharpie.

It was a pyramid with the sun on top.

From the movie script:

> DANIEL
>     Wait. Do you have a...um...sorry.
>
> [He looks around, **spotting a marker in Mitch's pocket and grabbing it.**]
>
> MITCH
>     Hey, hey, hey, don't...!
>
> [Daniel **has already begun drawing his little stick figures on the actual monitor screen.**]
>
> DANIEL
>    **Two figures on either side, praying beside a pyramid with the sun directly above it.**

[image]

And now... for the REAL fun part!!! The actual prop coverstone in the movie ***did not have the kneeling figures!!!*** (it was a production mistake)

[image]

Comment: Nice! I thought it was from the early days, I wonder why I thought they were Anubis Guards

Comment: So, Daniel thought they were two people praying to the sun, but in actuality it IS a pyramid with the sun above?

Comment: @m.t.bennett - was supposed to be 2 people. Look at model cartouches . This was just bad prop